# Custom column filter kendo ui grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

i've implemented a custom ui filter on the column labourmeansstatusenum. But the function doesn't get called and so the filter doesn't have custom values.
any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

```
       @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Presentation.Mvc.Models.LabourMeans.LabourMeansViewModel>()
.Name("grid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    /**/

    columns.Bound(s => s.LabourMeansStatusEnum)
        .ClientTemplate("# if (LabourMeansStatusEnum  == 0){#" +
                                                               "<div id='outofservice'><span class='label label-info arrowed-right arrowed-in'>" + @Label.OutOfService() + "</span></div>" +
                                                               "#}else if (LabourMeansStatusEnum  == 1){#" +
                                                               "<div id='intreatment'><span class='label label-info arrowed-right arrowed-in '>" + @Label.InTreatment() + "</span></div>" +
                                                               "#}else if (LabourMeansStatusEnum  == 2){#" +
                                                               "<div id='inservice'><span class='label label-info arrowed-right arrowed-in '>" + @Label.InService() + "</span></div>" +
                                                               "#}#"
                                                               )
                                                               .Title("Status")
                                                               .Filterable(filterable => filterable.UI("labourMeansStatusFilter"));


            .Filterable(filterable => filterable
            .Extra(false)
            .Operators(operators => operators
            .ForString(str => str.Clear()
            .IsEqualTo(@Label.IsEqualTo())
            .IsNotEqualTo(@Label.IsNotEqualTo())
            ))
            )


            .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
            .Pageable()
            .Scrollable()
            .Sortable()
            .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .Sort(sort => sort.Add("Id").Ascending())
                .PageSize(10)
                .Model(model => model.Id(s => s.LabourMeans.LabourMeans.Id))
                .Read(read => read.Action("LabourMeans_Read", "LabourMeans"))
               )

        )
```

the js filter function:

```
function labourMeansStatusFilter(element) {
    alert("test");
    element.kendoDropDownList({
        dataSource: [
            { Name: "Parent1", Id: 1 },
            { Name: "Parent2", Id: 2 }
        ],
        dataTextField: "Name",
        dataValueField: "Id"
    });
    alert("test5");
}
```

Comment: Where did you place your filter UI function?

Answer (score 0):

From what I've discovered, the custom filter method never gets called for an enum type.  I'm not sure if this is a bug in Kendo, or by design, but perhaps you can work around it by exposing a wrapper property to convert from/to a string representation of your enum?

Comment: You need to provide more information/code sample for this post to be an answer.